# Understanding Gradient Descent Algorithms?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Given the gradient descent algorithm:
$$x_{i+1} = x_i - \alpha_iD_i\nabla f(x_i)$$
with $\alpha_i$ suffiently small and $D_i > 0$ (positive definite)

I was under the assumption and the algorithm will always converge to a global minimum if $f$ is convex or to a local minimum. Is this not the case?

Does $f$ have to be convex for a global minimum to be found? In general, is gradient descent really finding a stationary point? with further analysis being required to determine if it's a min/max/inflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some provisos (in addition to the obvious requirement that $f$ is sufficiently smooth).

1. You cannot take $\alpha_i$ to be arbitrarily small. An easy counterexample is that if you always choose $\alpha_i=0$, clearly your algorithm just stays put at the initial guess and won't converge to any kind of critical point. You need $\alpha_i$ to both be small enough to guarantee that each step decreases the energy, yet also large enough to guarantee a sufficient decrease each step. (Take a look at some articles about line searches, or about the [Wolfe condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfe_conditions) in particular, for more information.)
2. Similarly you cannot take $D_i$ to have arbitrarily large eigenvalues. For instance, consider what happens if you set $\alpha_i=1$ and $D_i = 2^i I$.
3. It's possible for gradient descent to diverge to infinity. This can happen even if $f$ is convex (consider $f(x)=x$ for the simplest counterexample). In cases where gradient descent diverges, one can argue that there is a "minimum at infinity" but you need to be a bit careful about how to make this precise as formally gradient descent is *not* converging in these cases.

That said, suppose gradient descent does converge to some point. This point *might* be a saddle point, or even a local maximum (if $x_0$ is a saddle point, you will never leave it, for example). But it's very unlikely. You will converge to a local minimum for almost all starting points and moreover if you do converge to a saddle point, you can "slide off" by applying a small random perturbation to your solution and solving again.

If $f$ is convex, all critical points of $f$ are global minima and so, if gradient descent converges, it does so to a global minimum. You *might* also converge to a global minimum if $f$ is not convex. Depends on the initial guess, step size, preconditioner, line search strategy... there are no guarantees.